# I authenticated a user from IdS4, how do I use this info in my MVC client?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, identityserver4, identity

I've got a user authenticated via IdS4, along with a few claims and a role, now I'm lost about what to with it. The general flow for the user is: Go to my site, log in redirects to IdS4 server. They enter their username/password, and redirect back to my site, along with cookies set.

I've not seen much beyond authentication in the tutorials I've found.
Should/How do I persist the user? Should I set up Identity on my MVC site? I'm just looking for a general idea, I think I can figure out the specifics, at this point my general Googling hasn't turned up much.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add ASP.Net Identity to manage users in your client MVC application , or directly use EF Core to store users in database without ASP.Net Identity .

But the problem is why you want to perisit or manage users in your client application ? You are using Identity Server to do authentication and IDS will connect the database/configration file  to validate user and fill user claims , if you want to manage users/roles , you can add apis(CURD operations to user database) as protected resource , and your client app acquire access token to access that apis to perform user management . So that user management operations are share to clients which have permission to get api's access token . But if you want to manage specific users which only available to one client , you can mix asp.net identity and IDS4 authentication in client app .

Comment: That might be the part I was missing... I don't need to persist the users. I wasn't sure what the idea was once we authenticated. I'm not sure how to deal with roles or claims to authorize once I've authenticated, but I think at least I now know a better question to ask.

Comment: @spuppett ， you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59172472/5751404) code sample to involve user's roles in tokens .